# ASP.NET MVC Assign Roles when using custom authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, authorization

I am using MongoDB to store users and passwords (instead of sql).  I have my own mechanism for assigning roles to users.  I would like to decorate my controller actions with roles, as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
```

My login code looks like this:

```
if (mongo.AuthenticateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
}
```

What is the simplest way for me to 'stamp' a users roles onto the user when they first login (the database will provide me with the role names, I just need to set them within the users context).  I guess I'm looking for my code to look something like this:

```
if (mongo.AuthenticateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    if ((mongo.IsAdmin)
    {
        // How do I grant the admin role???
        SomeSortOfUserContext.Add('Administrators');????????
    }
    FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add roles to User Principal in Application_AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax.

Check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043732/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082703-1.aspx) out;